# How do I remove a specific builtin kernel module from a yocto linux build?

Tags: linux-device-driver, yocto

I am trying to install a new version of an ASIX usb driver on a development board. Unfortunately, the old version of the driver is built-in to the kernel.

Now I am trying to recompile the kernel without the offending builtin driver. I'm using `yocto`, but I don't know what the best way is to figure out exactly where that driver is coming from, and remove it from the build.

Before trying to rebuild the kernel, I installed a new version of the driver as a loadable module, but was unable to load and bind the device to it because the builtin module had taken the name `asix` already.

I tried recompiling the driver with a new name `asix_new` and using a `udev` rule to disconnect the relevant device from the old builtin `asix` driver and connecting it to the `axix_new` loadable driver. This didn't work for more hazy reasons. My best guess is that the device didn't like being disconnected, but I can't tell for sure.

I have also tried using:

```bash
$ bitbake {PROJECT} -c menuconfig
$ bitbake {PROJECT} -c diffconfig
```

then deselecting what I believe are the only two USB ethernet dongle drivers from Asix (`CONFIG_USB_NET_AX8817X` and `CONFIG_USB_NET_AX88179_17A`), moving the resulting `.cfg` file into the appropriate place then adding that file to a `.bbappend` file as described in the [yocto docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#configuring-the-kernel). But when I rebuild the project and flash it to the board, I still get the error that `asix` is builtin:

```
$ modprobe -r asix    
modprobe: FATAL: Module asix is builtin.
```

I'll also add that `modinfo` provides no information here:

```
$ modinfo asix
modinfo: ERROR: Module asix not found.
```

Comment: Does your new config change make it successfully to the final config? You can check the final config in `built/tmp/work/$ARCH/$LINUX_RECIPE_NAME/linux-default-build-or-similar/.config` file